# React Native - Navigation library used in Instagram and facebook?

Tags: react-native

I want to know how is navigation handled officially in instagram and facebook. There is no official navigation by react native community.

Comment: This is a little broad. Are you asking about specific libraries? Strategies?

Comment: They use probably use `react-native-navigation` but also recommend `react-navigation` (I prefer the latter) you can read more at the official RN docs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation#docsNav

Comment: Im trying to ask everything they do to implement navigation because I have been trying to make an app which has some complex navigation features which is leaving me switch between various navigation libraries. In instagram the navigation is quite sweetly handled and performance is so optimised made me wonder what they do